# How to redirect out put of xargs when using sed

Tags: linux, redirect, sed, xargs

Since swiching over to a better management system I am wanting to remove all the redundant logs at the top of each of our source files. In Notepad++ I was able to achieve the result by using "replace in files" and replacing matches to `\A(//.*\n)+` with blank. On Linux however I am having no such luck and am needing to resort to 'xargs' and 'sed'.

The sed expression I'm using is:

`sed '1,/^[^\/]/{/^[^\/]/b; d}'`

Ugly to be sure but it does seem to work.

The problem I'm having is when I try to run that through 'xargs' in order to feed it all the source files in our system I am unable to redirect the output to 'stripped' files, which I then intend to copy over the originals.

I want something in the line of:

`find . -name "*.com" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I file sed '1,/^[^\/]/{/^[^\/]/b; d}' "file" > "file.stripped"`

However I'm having grief passing the ">" through to the receiving environment (shell) as I'm already using too many quote marks. I have tried all manner of escaping and shell "wrappers" but I just can't get it to play ball.

Anyone care to point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Slarti.

Comment: Does your sed implementation support the `-i` option?

Comment: Are, yes it does. That makes life a lot easier. I'll give it a go and get back to you ;)

Comment: Why should you go with -exec option in find. Something similar like this, `find . -name "*.com" -type f -print0 -exec sed '1,/^[^\/]/{/^[^\/]/b; d}' {} > "file.stripped" \;`

Comment: I have tried using find's "-exec" option but couldn't get it to work either.  As it is it took me so long to wright the question using my phone that the office acutely closed and I had to leave before trying any of these suggestions but I believe your suggestion would either append everything to the file literally called "file.stripped" or continually overwrite the same file with whatever the current version pc "{}" was at the time.  Note substituting "file.stripped" for "{}.stripped" doesn't work either, it just creates a file called "{}.stripped".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a similar scenario with a simpler sed expression just as an example, see if it works for you:

I created 3 files with the string "abcd" inside each:

```
# ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5 Oct  6 09:05 test.aaaaa.com
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5 Oct  6 09:05 test2.aaaaa.com
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5 Oct  6 09:05 test3.aaaaa.com
# cat test*
abcd
abcd
abcd
```

Running the find command as you showed using the -exec option instead of xargs, and replacing the sed expression for a silly one that simply replaces every "a" for "b" and the option -i, that writes directly do the input file:

```
# find . -name "*.com" -type f -print0 -exec sed -i 's/a/b/g' {} \;
./test2.aaaaa.com./test3.aaaaa.com./test.aaaaa.com
# cat test*
bbcd
bbcd
bbcd
```

In your case it should look like this:

```
# find . -name "*.com" -type f -print0 -exec sed -i '1,/^[^\/]/{/^[^\/]/b; d}' {} \;
```

Comment: Thank you. That has indeed worked perfectly. Out of completeness though, any idea how one would redirect the output?

Comment: This can't be achievied using the xargs -I option because after the ">" sign used for redirecting output it understands it's not a part of the command arguments anymore, hence why it doesn't replace the "file.stripped" for the actual filename "find" gives you and ends up creating a literal "file.stripped" file.

You could write a script using the "for" command in conjuction with "find" and "xargs" to achieve that, but it's not the smartest nor easiest way to do it.

Also, don't forget to upvote my answer. ;)
Cheers!